# Negative arc length value. True or not?

Tags: integration, derivatives, definite-integrals, arc-length

I saw a post about this and someone said the arc length is an integral of a positive function, so it is positive.
But by solving this exercise I found the arclength as a negative value. 
The arc length for $ y= ln (1-x^2)$ from x=0 to x=1/2.
The result I found is $L= -ln(2)-ln(3/2)+1/2 = -0.5986 $. I calculated it by myself and then I use an online program to calculate it and it gives the same number.
So, is it true? Or can't an arc length have a negative value?

Comment: Maybe it is the integral of the absolute value... See Kristopher Tapp, [Differential Geometry of Curves and Surfaces (Springer, 2016)](https://books.google.it/books?id=kfIqDQAAQBAJ&pg=PA4)

Comment: No, that can't possibly be correct. You have made a mistake somewhere. If you showed your working, we might be able to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mistake was in taking the square root of

$$1+\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^2 = \left(\frac{x^2+1}{x^2-1}\right)^2$$

This is $\dfrac{x^2+1}{1-x^2}$, not $\dfrac{x^2+1}{x^2-1}$, because $x^2-1$ is negative for $x\in[0,\frac12]$.

Answer (score -2):

Based on your definition of arc length your first step is wrong.  Your function is not a positive function, actually $y=\ln (1 - x^2) \leq 0$ on $(-1,1)$.

So to use your definition of arc length, you need to apply it to $-y$.  This is the answer for $y$ as well, since distance and angle between points in the plane is preserved by mirror reflections

Comment: This is just wrong.

Comment: it's wrong that given positive function $f$, $f$ and $-f$ have the same arc length on the same interval?

Comment: Not wrong, just irrelevant. It does nothing to explain the OP's error.

Comment: I think it's appropriate given the level of detail given in OP's attempted solution.  They got the opposite sign, and first and foremost it's not clear they even applied the definition correctly or know the definition.  Obviously I can agree your answer is superior, and OP is lucky that someone took the time to reverse engineer. But I can't agree that my answer wouldn't solve a question, even if it creates a new one

Comment: But Nazim, the formula for the arc length starts by squaring the derivative. So replacing $y$ with $-y$ doesn't achieve anything.